# How do I compare date from database and current date in ms access using C#?

Tags: c#, database

what will be the ms access query for comparing date from database to current date ?

below is the code i have written .

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Product WHERE Insertiondate = dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToString()";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            TodaydataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            connection.Close();

            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use parameters. This code doesn't even try to insert the current date value concatenating string, It just search for a date with this impossible value 'dateTimePicker.Value.Date.ToString()' that's not a date

Comment: I have inserted the date in my data base

Comment: Do you have inserted dates complete with time informations? IE '10/09/2020 15:45:50' If yes then it is highly improbable that a seach for equality will find anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Date Time picker value as  a parameter. Try like:

```
...
    command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Product WHERE Insertiondate = ?";
    command.Parameters.Add("@Date, OleDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker.Value;
...
```

Comment: OP is using `System.Data.OleDb` and NOT `System.Data.SqlClient` `SqlDbType` enum need to be replaced with `OleDbType` enum and it should be` Insertiondate = ?` and not `Insertiondate = @Date`

Comment: I have used OledB type .

Answer (score 0):

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Product WHERE Insertiondate = Date()";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            TodaydataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            connection.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
```